# cocoa: how can i convert nsdate to nstimeinterval in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

```
 NSDate *newDate=[newDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:difference];
```

Now I want to convert this newDate to NStimeInterval.

How can I do this conversion?

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` represents the time between two dates; what do you want to calculate your date *from*?

Comment: i have this new date of type nsdate . but, in my case i have to pass the parameter of type nstimeinterval.how can i pass nsdate as nstimeinterval. conversion is required right?

Comment: and here i am adding nsdate with nstimeinterval.

Comment: Where are you passing it?  The documentation for the API should tell you what the time interval represents.

Comment: actually i have data on the fly for which i am using singleton class . since i can't initialize an nstimeinterval instance. i am using nsdate for initialization so please tell me how to convert an nsdate to nstimeinterval

Comment: Use any of the `timeIntervalSince...` methods.  Just be consistent converting to/from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NDDate` and `NSTimeInterval` are two diferent things, you cannot convert a `NSDate` to a `NSTimeInterval` and vice-versa.

`NSDate` represents an absolute date and `NSTimeInterval` represents the time between two dates.

However you can create a NSTimeInterval from a reference date with this method:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

You can do it like this:

```
NSDate *referenceDate = /* Your reference date */
NSDate *date = /* Your date */
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:referenceDate];
```

Answer (score 2):

As I have mentioned in the comments above, you need to know what you want the `NSTimeInterval` to represent as it's the distance between two points in time (i.e. two `NSDate` instances).

If you want it to represent the time between your `newDate` and 01-Jan-2001 GMT you can use:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
```

([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)).

However if you want it to represent the time since another *reference date*, you need to create that reference date as an `NSDate` object and use:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate;
```

([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate%3a)).

Answer (score -1):

Just a bit shorter:

```
NSDate *date = ...

NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

And to get it back:

```
date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timeInterval];
```